# How to convert NSArray values into CGRect

Tags: iphone, nsarray, cgrect

Actually I have a Xml file, after xml parsing,I get the values for frame position and frame size.I stored those values in an arra. now I have to give the array values for my imageview,so I need to convert those values into CGRect.,The NSlog shows "my frame is ( 0, 0 ), ( 768, 1024 )"

Can any one please help me out.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Can you please refine what you have and what you need and maybe provide a code snippet if applicable.

Comment: Actually I have a Xml file, after xml parsing,I get the values for frame position and frame size.I stored those values in an arra. now I have to give the array values for my imageview,so I need to convert those values into CGRect.,The NSlog shows "my frame is ( 0, 0 ), ( 768, 1024 )"..

Comment: I'm sure you'll get your answer as soon as you improve your question so others will know what you're talking about. Post your parsing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To store CGPoint in NSArray:

```
NSArray *points = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(5.5, 8.3)],[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(11.9, 8.5)],nil];
```

### To retrieve CGPoint from array:

From array to cgPoint variable.

```
NSValue *val = [points objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint p = [val CGPointValue];
```

This may helping to you

Happy codeing

Comment: I am not supposed to give CGPointMake(5.5, 8.3)]..like that, I need to take that values from an Array and  the array values taken from an xml file.